# Obtener valores no repetidos de un subarray PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tardes necesito que me ayuden con un problemita que tengo lo explico:
tengo un array que a su vez tiene un subarray, este es el array:

```
result=array();
result=( [GERENCIA] => Array
    (
        [2018-07-17] => 1
        [2018-08-14] => 4
        [2018-08-15] => 3
    )

[BARCO CAMPOVERDE DOUGLAS GEOVANNY] => Array
    (
        [2018-08-14] => 2
    )

[FUENTES HENRIQUEZ JUDITH ESPERANZA] => Array
    (
        [2018-08-14] => 4
    )

[PEREZ GARCIA MAURICIO JOSEPH] => Array
    (
        [2018-08-14] => 1
    )

)
```

entonces de este array tengo que obtener las fechas pero que o esten repetidas es decir tengo que obtener:
fechas(2018-07-17,2018-08-14,2018-08-15
) 
hasta el moemento logré obtener las fechas y las almacene dentro de un array:

```
Array(
[0] => 2018-07-17
[1] => 2018-07-17
[2] => 2018-08-14
[3] => 2018-08-15
[4] => 2018-08-14
[5] => 2018-08-14
[6] => 2018-08-14
[7] => 2018-08-14
[8] => 2018-08-14
[9] => 2018-08-14
[10] => 2018-08-14
[11] => 2018-08-14
[12] => 2018-08-15
[13] => 2018-08-15
[14] => 2018-08-15
[15] => 2018-08-15
[16] => 2019-06-14)
```

de este necesito obtener solo las fechas que no se repiten

espero que me ayuden muchas gracias

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora? puedes publicarlo para que podamos ayudarte mejor?

Comment: No se entiende que queres, porque las fechas que das de ejemplo, una esta repetida..

Comment: Si necesitas agregar informacion por favor usar el boton [edit] y agregala en la pregunta

Comment: ahi esta como tengo hasta ahora, aun no logro obtener los que no se repiten

Comment: Hola, como ya obtuviste todas las fechas dentro de un array, puedes usar `array_unique()` para eliminar las fechas repetidas, para ver como funciona puedes revisar la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php). Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias eso necesitaba...